# Does glTF supports morph target / shape keys for CURVES shapes?

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

I have a Blender file that contains some **curves** shapes.
These **curves** have some shape keys and I'd like to export it to a glTF file to be consumed by Three.js.

The problem is that exported glTF does not include the shape keys animations for the **curves**.

Comment: Sorry, glTF only supports meshes, not curves.

Comment: As emackey said, you're going to have to convert your curves into a tessellated mesh before exporting with glTF.

Comment: Blender's paths/edges and points can also be exported, after https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/717, not just triangle meshes. But curves must still be converted to one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glTF 2.0 format supports triangle meshes, lines/edges, and points. It does not directly support curves or NURBS. Blender's glTF exporter does have the ability to export all three primitive types (in recent versions) or to [bake static curves and surfaces to meshes](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/1132), but I don't think that it can bake *animations* on those curves. I think you would need to do that before exporting from Blender, and I'm not sure how — https://blender.stackexchange.com/ might be the place to ask on that topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Don! It saved me days.